# Are there any issues with my Entity Relationship diagram?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

[My Entity Relationship Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atrUa.png)

My ER diagram designed for the Orders database about customers and their orders for
a company. Each item
in the database must have an “owning” salesman, whether or not it is being ordered.

**With that being said I was wondering whether there were any issues with my diagram? What do you suggest I should change?**

Should I remove the customer and salesman attributes?

Comment: Are you aking about  issues concerning database design or concerning subject matter analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure but I think in your the Address Entity is extra its a attribute customer only so why you create address as a separate attribute.

Please refer the attach image to correct your different relationship with attributes.[image]